# Get Nuget packages with debug build so source link debugging works properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With source link enabled in VisualStudio I can step inside 3rd party code (also with resharper).  However when I am stepping through the code it can behave oddly because the Nuget packages are built in release mode so the compiler optimizes certain things away so certain breakpoints wont hit and variables wont be inspectable.

Is there anyway to get Nuget packages with a debug build instead so that the debugging works better?

Comment: It's really up to the package maintainer to make them available.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg
If have personally at times simply removed the nuget packages and used the 3rd party github sources to debug with.

Comment: Also check your VS Options Debugging > Symbols and see if you have the Nuget.org Symbol Server enabled.